# 2.4G keyboard with rasbain on v pi 2 model b

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, keyboard

I have a raspberry pi model b. I installed rasbain form [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). it was the minimal option. when it booted everything was ok. I plugged in my normal USB cord keyboard and it did not see it. Also my 2.4G keyboard. any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you plug in the keyboard before booting? I've never had any trouble with keyboards not showing up on any Pi. A corded keyboard should just work, and I've had wireless dongled ones come up too, Logitech and cheapo brands too. Most of those are 27MHz, not 2.4GHz, but they should both work as long as you're using the right USB dongle-- the USB port shouldn't know the difference.

Comment: I plug the dongle in before boot. no change. still does not see

Comment: Have you checked the keyboard with a PC or another machine? Otherwise, try a different USB port on the Pi? This stuff should work without much effort.

Comment: tried different ports. nope

Comment: All I can think of is 1) try different keyboards and mice, 2) burn the OS again, and 3) try a different Pi. These are the first steps, and it is odd that you're stuck at this point. I wonder if the Pi's USB ports got fried somehow or if something else is wrong with the Pi that is holding you back. Is the Pi in a case, or could the bottom have made contact with metal at some point when powered on? Sorry I can't think of anything else, good luck.